# compiling c++ program with intel compiler icpc in linux

Tags: linux, icc

I have installed intel compiler Intel® Parallel Studio XE 2015 and I have written simple hello world program at desktop.

then I can't figure how can I run this cpp file.

I have tried as

```
icpc helloworld.cpp
```

but it says  command not found.

Answer (score 7):

You need to have icpc in your PATH. If you do know where Intel compiler is installed then append the PATH env variable.
If you don't, search for icpc binary.

```
~> find / -name icpc
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.040/bin/intel64/icpc
```

Once you've found it, a convenient way of changing your environment is to source a script which comes with the compiler.

```
~> source /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.040/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
~> which icpc
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.040/bin/intel64/icpc
```

This adding-to-path procedure is explained on Intel website [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/setting-up-the-build-environment-for-using-intel-c-or-fortran-compilers#composer).